# JSX element type 'HTMLImageElement' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
I am trying an example with React Native and Typescript and for the following code: 

<Image
        style={{
          width: 51,
          height: 51,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
        }}
        source={{ uri: portretPhoto }}
        style={styles.uploadedImage}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
```

I get error:
**JSX element type 'HTMLImageElement' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'HTMLImageElement' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.**

How do I fix it?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/21242#issuecomment-342485894

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `Image` defined globally. You need to import the one from `react-native`